# how to call devenv to build some .vcproj with specific building macro in a solution (containing many .vcproj)?

Tags: rebuild, devenv, vcproj

all!

There are many vc projects in my solution. i can call devenv.exe xxx.sln to build/rebuild all these projects together. Also i can right-click some specific project and rebuild it.

My question: how to do the same thing of "right-click and rebuild" when i use devenv.exe ?

I want to rebuild the same project with different building macro --- setting "PreprocessorDefinitions" in .vcproj

another question: is there a simple way to replace the value of PreprocessorDefinitions in the .vcproj? im now using the python to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`devenv` has the command line option `/command` to run a command on start up: could this be used?

[Devenv Command Line Switches](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xee0c8y7.aspx)

Comment: i use python to modify .vcproj and then build it.